# Choropleth map from voronoi map from a set of coordinates (d3+leaflet)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, voronoi, choropleth

*[Repost](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/291778/choropleth-map-from-voronoi-map-from-a-set-of-coordinates-d3leaflet) from gis.stackexchange.com*

I have a csv file with a set of coordinates with the following structure: `id,name,latitude,longitude` (24 values).

Those 24 points represent coordinates in a city. I would like to get a **voronoi map** with those coordinates as centroids, and **then colour the polygons as if it were a choropleth map**. The result of this will be a map to be published on a web dashboard, so I will be using js-only frameworks.

I've been following [this tutorial](https://chriszetter.com/blog/2014/06/15/building-a-voronoi-map-with-d3-and-leaflet/) and [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/shimizu/925bd1a92b63753608ef) (leaflet+voronoi), but it's hard to find:

1. Tutorials with current/modern versions of d3 and/or leaflet.
2. Tutorials or articles on how to do the mapping process I need (coordinates>voronoi>choropleth).

Currently I am following the [d3.voronoi](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#voronoi-diagrams-d3-voronoi) section in the d3 API docs in order to understand how to generate the regions/polygons, but I don't know how to process those in order to generate the choropleth map using leaflet and mapbox.

I also tried using [turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) using [polygon](http://turfjs.org/docs/#polygon) to turn my coordinates into a `FeatureCollection`, then `turf.voronoi` and then using `geoJson` method from Leaflet, without success.

Which method would you recommend to do this?

Comment: take this example apart, replace with your data http://mashup.mesowest.net/voroWeather.html